# Graphics messed up when I try to reskin the game in Android Studio

Tags: graphics, android-studio

I need a little help. I'm new in Android Studio, I have a game where I want to reskin the design. First of all when I install it on my phone with the original files the game run perfectly without problems. When I try to reskin the photos in my assets folder, I save it, build it in APK file, I install the game and then the graphics is messed up. Here is screenshot of the game after the reskin. 
Sorry for my bad English...

[image: the graphics]

Comment: Did you replace the graphics at the exact same location on the images?

Comment: What did you do to reskin it? Just replace the assets? This looks like you replaced an atlas image and the new one follows a different structure

Comment: I replaced them and now everything is okay. Thank you @Sidar